# Int32 Is DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I was writing a console program and I attempted to convert `Console.ReadLine()` to `Int32`, well instead of typing `ReadLine()`, I accidentally typed `WriteLine()`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LinqIntegersDemo.cs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] nums = new int[10];
            var sorted = from c in nums orderby c descending select c;
            int x = 0;

            foreach (var n in nums)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter an integer >> ");
                nums[x] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.WRITELINE());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I (obviously) got an error but instead of it saying something expected, it says that I cannot convert `void` to `System.DateTime`.

Why is it saying that `Int32` is `System.DateTime`?

Comment: It's not saying `int` is `DateTime`, it's saying that it can't convert the result of `Console.WriteLine()` (i.e. `void`) to `System.DateTime`, which makes sense because you can't convert nothing to something. `Convert.ToInt32` has an overload that takes a `DateTime` value (seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch56d3w9(v=vs.110).aspx)) and all it does is throw an `InvalidCastException` which is the error you're seeing. I don't have an answer as to why it's choosing *that* overload, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Convert.ToInt32` has an overload that accepts a:

- DateTime
- Boolean
- Byte
- Char
- Double
- Decimal
- Int16
- Int64
- Object
- String
- and many more, see the documentation for the rest

When it couldn't match any of the overloads (`void` isn't a valid option) it just picks one of the overloads that failed in the step that determined there were no valid overloads and uses that in the error message.  In this case it happened to choose the `DateTime` overload, but it could just as easily have chosen any of the other one-argument overloads.

Comment: Does it pick them in any specific order?

Comment: @Slappywag Nothing meaningful, certainly nothing that you'd ever want to rely on.

Answer (score 0):

It's not saying that `Int32` is `System.DateTime`

Compiler is just trying to guess: it think you wanted to call `Convert.ToInt32(DateTime dt);` and instead you call `Convert.ToInt32(void);` (being `void` the return type of `Console.WriteLine()`)

[Convert.ToInt32()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx) has a lot of overloads: none of them are defined without parameters. 
I don't know why it decides to pick up the overload with DateTime vs (e.g) the overload with a string or a boolean: in any case there is no overload that accept no parameter, so it cannot compile the code

Answer (score 0):

The `Convert.ToInt32` has lots of overloaded methods for the different types. It probably defaulted to the DateTime type.